# Apostrophes/single quotes in question titles aren't escaped in code for share buttons

Tags: bug, status-completed

The code that prepares the Facebook and Twitter share buttons has a variable that receives the title of the question as a single-quoted string. [Some questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12267/gamepad-for-assassins-creed-for-pc-not-working) have an apostrophe (or single quote) in their title which isn't properly escaped as part of this process, causing a JavaScript error. This breaks the share buttons, making them unusable on those questions. The value assigned to the `shareMsg` variable should be properly escaped to prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our pesky encoder assumes all js strings are wrapped in `"` and not my beloved `'`, causing this issue.

A fix will be deployed shortly.