# Tooltip text for markdown hyperlinks in comments doesn't render single quotes correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, markdown, hyperlinks

[image]

See e.g. [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/8008/#comment-44958)

Comment: possibly related to [Apostrophes/single quotes in question titles aren't escaped in code for share buttons](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77474/146482)

Comment: Nope, it's not.

Comment: For those like me who didn't know about the ability to add tooltip text in comments, the markdown is `[text](url "title")`.

Comment: @Kevin [it's rather well hidden...](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#advanced-links "but it's there...")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem: Too little encoding makes crackers happy, too much encoding makes users unhappy.

Suggested solution: Correct amount of encoding.

Status of solution: Fixed in the next build.

Comment: thanks. And [how will I know when the next build is rolled](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106523/how-to-know-when-a-new-build-of-stackexchange-is-rolled "also, it's a tooltip text containing a single quote") so I can accept your answer?