# How to know when a new build of Stack Exchange is rolled out?

Tags: support, stack-exchange

Bugs are often said to be fixed in the [next build](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106520/tooltip-text-for-markdown-hyperlinks-in-comments-doesnt-render-single-quotes-cor/106522#106522). But how to tell builds apart as a mere mortal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a build number in the bottom right corner of every page (on Meta currently 2011.9.17.6). Note there are two build groups: One group is Meta.SO + Meta.SE, the other one is everything else.

Comment: Is this to mean that meta.*.stackexchange is the same build as *.stackexchange?

Comment: @MatthewRead: Orly!? So meta.^stackoverflow.com share rep with their parent sites?

Comment: While that's true, it has nothing at all to do with the build groups.

Comment: I guess [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) is a fourth build group?

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Area51 is totally different code, these build groups (of which these days there are only two) refer only to the Q&A sites.