# Inline diff not displaying full revision coverage

Tags: bug, status-completed, revisions-list, diff

There's something wrong with the inline diff in Revision 3 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7581595/revisions) (compare with source diff)

Don't really know how to explain it, so I'll let the revisions speak for themselves. The inline diff seems to have given up outputting anything at the `<br/>`.

As an aside, formatting the headers and bullet lists underneath that numbered list was a right pain in the neck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it was indeed the `<br/>` (to be precise, it was the self-closing `/` at the end) that wasn't handled correctly and thus broke here (in particular due to the condensing of long diffs). I've made two changes:

1. This particular case is now handled correctly, and
2. in case similar issues happen in the future, this will a) be logged in our error log, and b) the condensing bails out and shows the uncondensed version instead, so nothing is hidden from the diff view, even if there's a bug causing the condensing to fail.

This goes live with the next build.

Comment: Nice one! Shall verify and accept. How often do builds get pushed out?

Comment: Ususally between one and maybe five times per day. Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106523/how-to-know-when-a-new-build-of-stackexchange-is-rolled-out

Comment: Nice one; and I can verify the fix. Top qual.